# replace just one line in varchar type field in mysql table

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-update

a disaster has almost happened. I wanted to remove a 'line' from the comment column in one of my table on the MySQL database, but it removed all contents of the column. here is what i ran:

```
update itemlist 
set comment = replace(comment,'\nThu Apr 30 2015: item is outdated now', '') 
WHERE instr( comment, 'Thu Apr 30 2015: item is outdated' ) >0
```

by mistake (problem in program logic) the wrong entry was made ("\nThu Apr 30 2015: item is outdated now") in column comment. The comment field contains lot of other data for each row. After i ran the above command, i lost of that, command simply replaced it all by a blank.

FORTUNATELY I have a backup of the table. Now I want to update the comment column from the backup *but* not this line. Pl help how can i do this?

sorry for delay, i was not keeping well.

SAMPLE data:

1. sample full text: (dont know what is screwed up with the formatting following has 3 lines, each line starts with a date.)

   Fri Apr 10 2015: item is added
   Mon Apr 20 2015: item is modified
   Thu Apr 30 2015: item is outdated <<< wriong entry to be removed.

some are like this:

```
Fri Apr 10 2015: item is added
Mon Apr 20 2015: item is modified
Thu Apr 30 2015: item is outdated <<< wrong entry to be removed.
Fri May 1 2015: item is isolated.
```

2. itemlist does have a unique ID column which is the index on the table.

thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the *full* text you want to "edit"?

Comment: Does `itemlist` have an ID column?

Comment: sorry for delay, i was not keeping well.

Comment: 1. sample full text:
"Fri Apr 10 2015: item is added
Mon Apr 20 2015: item is modified
Thu Apr 30 2015: item is outdated <<< wriong entry to be removed."

some are like this:
"Fri Apr 10 2015: item is added
Mon Apr 20 2015: item is modified
Thu Apr 30 2015: item is outdated <<< wriong entry to be removed.
Fri May 1 2015: item is isolated."

2. itemlist does have a unique ID column which is the index on the table.

Comment: Sander,  itemlist does have a unique ID column which is the index on the table.